# BigQuery and dataflow

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow

when I go to query settings in bigquery sql workspace there is no option to change the query engine to cloud dataflow engine and the photo below is from the tutorial I'm watching [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW1A9.png)
but in my case it's missing

I'm trying to work with bigquery sql workspace and deploy my data processing pipelines to the cloud dataflow services as it was done in the tutorial I'm watching but the problem is that some options are missing.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the old UI. *Cloud Dataflow engine* has been now transferred from BigQuery's dashboard to Daflow's and it's now called *Dataflow SQL*. There you can create your queries and run jobs/pipelines.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/dataflow-sql-intro#pricing

Comment: The tutorial I think you might referring to: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dataflow-sql-streamingtax-example. Already reported a bug since it's outdated

Comment: do you know any good tutorials or courses for the new UI that I can see

Comment: This one should be okay to get started: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/dataflow-sql-intro. Could you verify that my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is now available under "Dataflow" service as "SQL Workspace"

[image: Dataflow - SQL Workspace]